# Issues with Log Shipping in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server

We're in the process of migrating a customer from a SQL Server 2012 environment to 2019.

I've been trying to get the log shipping up and running as it was in the old environment but I keep coming up against errors.

The first error I get is in the restore job on the secondary server:

```
2020-02-25 16:04:04.77  Skipped log backup file. Secondary DB: 'DB_Name', File: 'E:\LogShipping\DB_Name_20200225154501.trn'
2020-02-25 16:04:04.77  Error: Could not log history/error message. Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)
2020-02-25 16:04:04.77  Error: Failed to convert parameter value from a SqlGuid to a String.(System.Data) 
2020-02-25 16:04:04.77  Error: Object must implement IConvertible.(mscorlib)
```

If you google that, it leads you to a page suggesting the fix is to install cumulative update 2:  https://support.microsoft.com/sq-al/help/4537869/fix-log-shipping-agent-is-not-able-to-log-history-and-error-informatio

I tried installing that but immediately started noticing an issue where when you open Job Activity Monitor, the list of jobs does not load and you get an error message including the text "Failed to retrieve data for this request".  You also cannot do things like edit Log Shipping schedules for servers affected.  Nothing will work until you restart SQL Server Agent on the affected server.  If you check the job history, you can see that no scheduled tasks run during the time that SQL Server Agent is stalled.  SQL Server Agent doesn't appear to crash completely which is a shame in a way, because it should re-start itself in that case.

Searching for this error leads you to a dba.stackexchange.com page describing the same issue with the only resolution being uninstalling CU2.

I tried uninstalling CU2 but am immediately back to the original error message.

This leads me to believe that Log Shipping is broken in SQL Server 2019.

Is anyone actually using it successfully?

Did you come across either of these issues and manage to resolve them?

Should I be looking at mirroring or replication instead in 2019, or is Log Shipping still an acceptable warm-standby solution?

Comment: Logged this with Microsoft who were unable to tell me anything other than to restart the services.  I eventually came across this link:  https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/03/breaking-news-sql-server-2019-cu2-breaks-agent  Tried going to CU1 as suggested but that just took me back to the "Could not log history" problem.  I forwarded all those details to the person at MS dealing with my issue who told me that they were aware of the problem and it would indeed be addressed in CU3 but they couldn't tell me when.  Advice in the meantime is to never edit agent jobs, or not to use log shipping!

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. I installed [Cumulative Update 3 for SQL Server 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4538853/cumulative-update-3-for-sql-server-2019)
and it went away